# Vim syntax highlighting didn't work in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vim

Recently I reinstall ubuntu. When I install vim in new ubuntu 16.04 OS syntax highlighting of PHP, JS has gone.
I install vim by using this command

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

When syntax highlighting hasn't work, I reinstall vim by using this command.

```
sudo apt-get purge vim; sudo apt-get install vim
```

But still didn't work. Screenshot of PHP file which is opened by vim is given below.

[image]

Comment: I see monochrome syntax highlighting (bold, underline). Does vim think your terminal doesn't support colors? Which terminal emulator are you using? What is `$TERM` set to? What do `:set t_Co?` and `:set term?` say in vim?

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: @melpomene I used xterm-256color terminal. set t_Co didn't work

Comment: What is "didn't work" supposed to mean?

Comment: Nothing changed as I set "set t_Co"